# Frequence analysis in c, how do i get the whole ascii table inside of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, ascii

Im currently working on a school project where i am suppose to create a frequence analysis for strings so we can either encode or decode them. 
I need to somehow count how many times each char appears in the string, the strig is a random file that can be a whole page from a book or whatever so we need all the characters from the ascii table. 
Right now im strugling with getting an array filled with all the possible chars that could appear.

I have decided to go with the direction of an array of a struct that contains a char and a int that in my head are suppose to work so that the char is the key and the int how many times that specific char appears in the string. 
I need to get all 256 possible chars into the array but cant find a way to get the first 32.

```
  for (char c = NULL; c <= 'z' ; c++){
    ftabel[i].value = c;
    i++;
  }
```

I thought i could ddo something as simple as this but it doesnt work. If i however let the loop go from 
' ' it works perfectly fine. I also dont know what to put for the last element of the ascii. Thankful for all help.

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit encoding scheme, which means all encoded characters (printable and non-printable) will have values in the range `0` to `127` (inclusive). Creating an array of `128`  elements should not be that hard... ;)

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is a null *pointer*, not the "null value". If you want to loop from zero then use zero (i.e. `0`).

Comment: `'z'` is not the last element of the ASCII table, are looking for letters only, or all the elements of the table?

Comment: As for the frequency analysis, all you really need is an array of `128` integer elements, all initialized to zero (i.e. `int freq[128] = { 0 };`). Then use the ASCII-encoded character you read as an index into this array and increase the elements (as in `int c = getc(); ++freq[c];`).

Comment: Beware of characters not in the ASCII set, giving negative values.

Comment: The first 32 are 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and the last one is 127. Have you considered writing the numbers 0 and 127? (if you use `unsigned char` you can make it work up to 255)

Comment: We are suppose to use every char in the ascii table. It says in the exercise that we need to consider all 256 possible characters.

Comment: If we for example has to make table from a page from a book we need to know when one line is done and '\n' appears so that when we decode it it comes out the same if u encode that file

Comment: @forsb 1) The [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933413/frequence-analysis-in-c-how-do-i-get-the-whole-ascii-table-inside-of-an-array#comment105989308_59933413) is imprecise.  ASCII only defines 128 characters.  ASCII is a subset of `char`.  2) Too cope with 256 values, use `unsigned char` for table indexing.

Comment: @chux, i understand but i dont really know how to do it. The assignment says remember that all 256 possible characters needs to be in the table. We are doing huffman coding if that is any help

Comment: @forsb There are no differences between the 256 different characters and the first 256 different integers in this case. A character is just an integer. e.g. the character literal 'A' is the same as the integer 65 in ASCII. You can just iterate from the integer 0 to 255. `for (int  i = 0; c i 255; i++) {  ftabel[i].value = i; }`

Comment: @nos but when i do like that it does not give me all the characters i need all no capital chars will not get into the array :s, i assume i probably have to get greater knowledge of how c treats ascii

Comment: @forsb A `char` value is C is just an integer value.  On most systems, a `char` value is going to have 8 bits, and an actual `int` value will have 16, or most likely today 32 bits.  That's really the only difference when processing `char` values instead of `int` values.  It's the **display** of the `char` values where the difference really (and literally...) appears.

Comment: @forsb Well you have not posted the full code you are working with, so it is quite impossible to try to find the specific problem you have.

Comment: @nos Yes, i didnt fullt understand the issue before and therefore i thought the code i gave was enough. Since im swedish i needed the chars åäö and C needed 2 bytes to store them, so when i tried to print out which chars that had been found the program said it found chars like ñ etc. And that was because it had split upp åäö into 2 diffrent one sized bytes and then counted each byte as a sign. It will add them back togheter when im counting them later. Thanks for the help that you gave anyways. It gave me greater understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int freq[UCHAR_MAX] = {};
    uint8_t* text = (uint8_t*)"The 41-year-old NBA legend died Sunday morning in a helicopter crash in foggy conditions in Calabasas, California. Visibility was so low Sunday morning that Los Angeles police had grounded its helicopters, spokesman Josh Rubenstein said."
                "The helicopter crashed into a hillside, killing everyone on board. But the official cause of the crash has not been determined.";
    size_t len = strlen(text);

    while(*text)
    {
        freq[*text++]++;
    }

    printf("Histogram\n");
    char bars[len];
    memset(bars, '=', len);

    for(int i=0; i< UCHAR_MAX; ++i)
    {
        if (freq[i])
        {
            printf("%c(%03d)[0x%02X] : %.*s (%d)\n", isprint(i)? i: "?", i, i, freq[i], bars, freq[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4560KB
Histogram
 (032)[0x20] : ====================================================== (54)
,(044)[0x2C] : === (3)
-(045)[0x2D] : == (2)
.(046)[0x2E] : ==== (4)
1(049)[0x31] : = (1)
4(052)[0x34] : = (1)
A(065)[0x41] : == (2)
B(066)[0x42] : == (2)
C(067)[0x43] : == (2)
J(074)[0x4A] : = (1)
L(076)[0x4C] : = (1)
N(078)[0x4E] : = (1)
R(082)[0x52] : = (1)
S(083)[0x53] : == (2)
T(084)[0x54] : == (2)
V(086)[0x56] : = (1)
a(097)[0x61] : ======================= (23)
b(098)[0x62] : ===== (5)
c(099)[0x63] : ========== (10)
d(100)[0x64] : ================ (16)
e(101)[0x65] : ================================ (32)
f(102)[0x66] : ===== (5)
g(103)[0x67] : ======== (8)
h(104)[0x68] : =============== (15)
i(105)[0x69] : ============================= (29)
k(107)[0x6B] : == (2)
l(108)[0x6C] : ================ (16)
m(109)[0x6D] : ==== (4)
n(110)[0x6E] : ========================= (25)
o(111)[0x6F] : ======================== (24)
p(112)[0x70] : ===== (5)
r(114)[0x72] : ============== (14)
s(115)[0x73] : ===================== (21)
t(116)[0x74] : =============== (15)
u(117)[0x75] : ====== (6)
v(118)[0x76] : = (1)
w(119)[0x77] : == (2)
y(121)[0x79] : ====== (6)
```

Comment: hats a much better solution, but what about the rest of the characters like ESC and ≤?

Comment: `≤` is not in ASCII or Extended ASCII

Answer (score 0):

This is actually almost trivial, because the `char` value itself is all the index you need:

```
#include <limits.h>

// static, so it's initialized to zero
unsigned long long charCounts[ UCHAR_MAX + 1 ];

// Note the use of **unsigned** char
// `unsigned char` ensures any `char` value will
// not cause an improper access to charCounts[]
void countChars( const unsigned char *str )
{
    while ( *str )
    {
        ( charCounts[ *str ] )++;
        str++;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    .
    .
    .
```

Pedantically, there are only 128 true ASCII characters, but whoever specified "ASCII" for this might not be aware of that and may have meant ["extended ASCII"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) of some type and a full 256 characters.

Printing the `char` values isn't trivial if you want to print out the actual `char` itself - not all `char` values are printable, and some might cause display issues depending on your output device.  This would work somewhat:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void printCounts()
{
    // unsigned char ii here would infinite loop...
    // (yes, pedantically even `unsigned int` might)
    for ( unsigned int ii = 0; ii <= UCHAR_MAX; ii++ )
    {
        // get a printable char value
        unsigned char pp = ii;
        if ( !isprint( ii ) )
        {
            pp = '*';
        }

        printf( "'%c' (%02X): %llu\n", pp, ii, charCounts[ ii ] );
    }
}

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i think i have been a bit unclear about the actuall exercise im going to get a infile and from that i need to create a frequence table of all the characthers in that. I then need to "Huffman code(?)" that into binary represents and create a trie of that so i either can encode or decode it.