# Digit Frequency calculating code in C not working

Tags: c, string, digits, atoi

So, I was writing this code for counting the digit frequency i.e. the number of times the digits from 0-9 has appeared in a user inputted string(alphanumeric). So, I took the string, converted into integer and tried to store the frequency in "count" and print it but when I run the code, count is never getting incremented and the output comes all 0s. Would be grateful if anyone points out in which part my logic went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // takes string input
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    //turns the string to int
    int x = atoi(s);
    int temp = x, len = 0;
    //calculates string length
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x / 10;
        len++;
    }
    x = temp;
    //parses through the string and matches digits with each number
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(x % 10 == j){
                count++;
            }
            x = x / 10;
        }
        x = temp;
        printf("%d ", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've input the value as a string: so you've already got an array of the digit values (as characters). You don't need to convert to an integer and then back to individual digits. Just test that each character *is* a digit and convert to range `0..9` by subtracting `'0'`. You'll need an array length 10 to count the frequency of each digit. By converting to an integer, your algorithm will fail on, say `"123ABC123"` because it only extracted `123` and it will also fail on `"11111111111111111"` because you overflow an `int` and will *also* fail on `"01234"` because you'll lose the `0`.

Comment: `1024` digits? :-) You realize `atoi("2...<more than 10 digits>...3")` invokes Undefined Behaviour (and probably will return `2147483647`)?

Comment: When I compile and run the the program and enter “123”, the program prints “0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0”. So I do not see that “the output comes all 0s”. Certainly if you enter a number that is larger than an `int` can represent, the `atoi` will not work as you want, and you will get “wrong” output, but not likely all zeros. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I noticed the following: (1) There's no need to reallocate the buffer `s`. It's fine as it is. Just make sure you `free()` it when you're done. (2) You already know the length of the string, from calling `strlen()`. There's no need to do any trickery with integers - _unless_ you wanted to compare the results of the two methods. (3) There's no need to do integer trickery to extract individual digits from the value. You've already got a string containing all the digits. If `s[n]=='0'` then digit `n` is a zero, and so on.

Comment: One final point, and @pmg spotted it but I didn't. As long as you keep the number in a string, you can process as many digits as you like. It's only when you try to store it in an `int` that you hit problems with numerical limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a correct and reasonable digit-counting program:

- Do not allocate any buffer for this.
- Create an array to count the number of times each digit occurs. The array should have ten elements, one for each digit.
- Initialize the array to zero in each element.
- In a loop, read one character at a time.
- Leave the loop when the read routine (such as `getchar`) indicates end-of-file or a problem, or, if desired, returns a new-line or other character you wish to use as an end-of-input indication.
- Inside the loop, check whether the character read is a digit. If the character read is a digit, increment the corresponding element of the array.
- After the loop, execute a new loop to iterate through the digits.
- Inside that loop, for each digit, print the count from the array element for that digit.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is way to complicated for a very easy task. This will do:

```
void numberOfDigits(const char *s, int hist[10]) {
    while(*s) {
        if(isdigit(*s)) 
            hist[*s - '0']++;
        s++;
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
int main(void) {
    char buf[1024];
    int hist[10];

    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

    numberOfDigits(s, hist);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
        printf("Digit %d occurs %d times\n", i, hist[i]);
}
```

This can also be quite easily achieved without a buffer if desired:

```
int ch;
int hist[10];

while((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(isdigit(ch)) 
        hist[ch - '0']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input = 1223330;
    int freq[10] = {0};
    
    input = abs(input);
    while(input)
    {
        freq[input%10]++;
        input /= 10;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d: %.*s\n", i, freq[i], "*************************************************");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5668KB
0: *
1: *
2: **
3: ***
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: 
9:
```

This app is currently limited by the size of an `int` (approximately 9 or 10 digits).

You can update it to use a `long long` easily, which will get you to about 19 digits.

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381876/how-can-i-print-horizontal-and-vertical-histogram-in-c/50382134#50382134

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933413/frequence-analysis-in-c-how-do-i-get-the-whole-ascii-table-inside-of-an-array/59933543#59933543